# How i can disable TebleView Cell clicking by programing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

i used the custom table cell i have add UISwitch on cell but i want to disable clicking on hole cell, user only click on the Switch but not click on the cell of Table how it's possible ?

Comment: Do you still need to detect whether that particular cell was tapped on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Answer (score 1):

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

It will disable the selection. And ignore didSelectRowAtIndexPath